# How do I use Paypal on my website with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I'm developing a website with PHP and MySQL. How can I make it so that if you click the Paypal button and pay successfully it will change a string in the database from "Personal" to "Professional"?

Comment: You said your application is in C#, but you tagged this question with PHP instead. Could you clarify?

Comment: the application has nothing to do with the question i was just sating it i want the paypal thing for my website

Comment: I just replaced the php tag with the C# tag.

Comment: @John I've changed it back (and edited the question) because from his comment I think that he means his website is PHP, and on it he's selling/providing software written in C#. Please feel free to change it back if you think I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Jeremy: No problem. Based on the headline of the question I agree with you. I removed the C# tag now and also added the paypal tag. Please change again if there is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about PayPal Website Payments Standard (if you're not paying a monthly fee, you are), then you need to use [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn). You can either enable it account-wide from the profile tab of your account, or per payment button/link by setting the `notify_url` parameter.

PayPal will send an HTTP POST to your notify URL when a payment is completed. Your script at that URL should verify that the POST is authentic, then update the appropriate row in the database now that you know it's paid for.